# OrientDB: How to flatten nested heirarchy into a single record

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I have a structure that looks something like this:

[image]

How can I traverse my Page and get back a flat record so that each row represents all of data from the root node and its edges. My use case is that I'm producing a csv file.

so from the example above, i would like to create a row for each post. Each record should contain all fields from post, the language name, the page name, and the network name.

From what I can tell, when you do any kind of traversal, it only gives you the result of the final vertex and not any data from the vertices in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select *,out('posted_to').name as page,out('posted_to').out('is_language').name as language,out('posted_to').out('is_network').name as network from <class Post> unwind page,language,network
```

Comment: What would be the most efficient way to do this starting from a page vertex? Since I have many pages and those pages have 10s of thousands of posts, I would like to be able to do the query to get a page -> posts (filtered by date) -> flattened record.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If there are many posts per page, then anchoring the query on the Pages may be more efficient than starting with the Posts.

Ergo:

```
select focus.in() as post,
       focus.name as page,
       focus.out("is_language").name as language,
       focus.out("is_network").name as network
from (select @this as focus from Page)
unwind post, language, network, page

----+------+-----+----+--------+-------
#   |@CLASS|post |page|language|network
----+------+-----+----+--------+-------
0   |null  |#11:0|1   |Welsh   |1      
1   |null  |#11:1|1   |Welsh   |1      
2   |null  |#11:2|1   |Welsh   |1      
3   |null  |#11:3|1   |Welsh   |1      
4   |null  |#11:4|1   |Welsh   |1      
5   |null  |#11:5|1   |Welsh   |1      
6   |null  |#11:6|1   |Welsh   |1      
----+------+-----+----+--------+-------
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to expand all fields from the post rid that your query retrieves? Otherwise would I have to specify each field separately?  
ie.
focus.in()[name] as post_name,
focus.in()[posted_at] as posted_at

Comment: There is currently an OrientDB deficiency (or bug?) that prevents one from writing "select *, expand(post) from (ABOVE)" (where "ABOVE" is the query shown above). On the other hand, one can simply write `select from Post` :-)

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something simple. Are you saying that there is a way to `select from post` from the query above, or that my only option is to revert to anchoring the query on a post instead of on the page?

Comment: Yes, my point was very simple.  Since your Post entities are so numerous, I was suggesting that you consider using ODB to produce two separate tables, which you can (if necessary) join later (e.g. using the command-line utility `join`).