# OrientDB SQL - How to unwind multiple attributes from an inline collection

Tags: orientdb

Suppose there is a document with an inline collection of objects, as in the example below:

```
{ "name": "Alice", 
  "children": [{ "name": "Bob", "age": 3 }, { "name": "Charlie", "age": 7 }] 
}
```

I'd like to obtain one row per item in the collection, and each inner attribute as a separate column, such as this:

```
| name    | childName | childAge |
| Alice   | Bob       | 3        |
| Alice   | Charlie   | 7        |
```

I tried the following query, but it generates a Cartesian product:

```
select name, children.name as childName, children.age as childAge
from Employee
unwind childName, childAge
```

I've also managed to extract each child with the **expand** and **flatten** functions, but without any reference to its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is as follows:

```
  SELECT name, children.name as childName, children.age as childAge FROM (
    SELECT name, children FROM Employee UNWIND children
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to do the same thing.

The closest I can find in ODB is separating the children into vertices like in this question: [OrientDB: How to flatten nested heirarchy into a single record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428378/orientdb-how-to-flatten-nested-heirarchy-into-a-single-record)

I would prefer to do it how mongo handles it (Not exactly what I want, but the principal is there.): [MongoDB unwind multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373442/mongodb-unwind-multiple-arrays)

Failed attempts:

1. select name, children from Test UNWIND children
   [result from query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lArY9.png)
2. select value.name, value.age from (select expand(children) from Test)
   [result from query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jziMf.png)
   If there was a link to the parent this would work, but value.$parent returns empty.